# fit_transform Only Size-1 Arrays Can Be Converted To Python Scalars

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

From what I understand this error happens when I try to pass an array instead of a single value but I thought StandardScaler was supposed to accept a matrix.

For context on what data is being pulled, I process a directory of 1,000 garbage bin images that I later reshape. I thought reshaping would resolve the issue but here we are.

**EDIT**: Updated code to include imports and error messages, it should run with what's provided.

```py
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage.feature import hog
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.color import rgba2rgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

def returnImageArray(filename, directory = "./garbage bins/"):
    filePath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    image = Image.open(filePath)
    return np.array(image)

def processImageFeatures(image):
    features = image.flatten()
    grayscaleConversion = rgb2gray(rgba2rgb(image))
    hogify = hog(grayscaleConversion, block_norm='L2-Hys', pixels_per_cell=(16, 16))
    flatify = np.hstack(features)
    return flatify

allFeatures = []
for file in fileNames:
    image = returnImageArray(file)
    feat = processImageFeatures(image)
    allFeatures.append(feat)
    
allFeaturesArray = np.array(allFeatures, dtype=object)

print(allFeaturesArray.shape)
reshapedF = np.array(allFeaturesArray).reshape(-1, 1)
print(reshapedF.shape)
print(reshapedF[1])
scaler = StandardScaler()

 ##----
garbage = scaler.fit_transform(reshapedF) ##ERROR HERE: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
 ##----

pca = PCA(n_components=1000)
garbagePCA = scale.fit_transform(gabrage)

print(allFeaturesArray.shape)
#(1000,)
#(1000, 1)
#[array([196, 179, 146, ..., 187, 164, 255], dtype=uint8)]
```

**WARNING**

```
<ipython-input-6-6c460760299f>:7: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray   
    allFeaturesArray = np.array(allFeatures)
```

**ERROR**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-4533ce454d0d> in <module>
      6 scaler = StandardScaler()
      7 
----> 8 garbage = scaler.fit_transform(reshapedF)
      9 
     10 pca = PCA(n_components=1000)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    688         if y is None:
    689             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 690             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    691         else:
    692             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in fit(self, X, y)
    665         # Reset internal state before fitting
    666         self._reset()
--> 667         return self.partial_fit(X, y)
    668 
    669     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y)
    694             Transformer instance.
    695         """
--> 696         X = self._validate_data(X, accept_sparse=('csr', 'csc'),
    697                                 estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES,
    698                                 force_all_finite='allow-nan')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    418                     f"requires y to be passed, but the target y is None."
    419                 )
--> 420             X = check_array(X, **check_params)
    421             out = X
    422         else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    596                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    597                 else:
--> 598                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    599             except ComplexWarning:
    600                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

**IMAGE SET**

This is the list of directories returnImageArray() is retrieving images from.
[image]

Comment: Why `object`?  `np.array(allFeatures, dtype=object)`

Comment: It is advisable to provide a working piece of code, that is, including the import statements, so that someone who tries to reproduce the error you get does not spend time to recreate you issue.

Comment: Error and stack trace please

Comment: The reason I used "dtype=object" is because it was throwing a warning at me, should I remove it or is there a better way of dealing with the warning I'm receiving? Specifically, the warning was: ```<ipython-input-6-6c460760299f>:7: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray   allFeaturesArray = np.array(allFeatures)```

Comment: but even if I remove dtype, it seems to give the same results.

Answer (score 1):

The images have to be the exact same resolution because the shape of each individual image results in a differently sized matrix. Once they are the same resolution, it runs no problem.

Comment: That was the more generic meaning of my answer, you need to have the same number of features, either by having the same size of images or by fixing the number of features by keeping the minimum number across the images (if that makes sense). I have updated my answer to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

After studying your issue a little bit, I realize that it is relevant to hpaulj's question about the usage of `dtype=object`. I guess you used that to avoid the error you got when you tried to convert a list of arrays of different size to a single array.

The problem is that the `reshapedF` is an array of two objects, each an array itself of different size.

You need to create a single array that is the result of merging of other arrays, for example, by using `numpy.stack()` or `numpy.concatenate()` or whatever is appropriate to what you are trying to achieve.

The point is that the input to the `StandardScaler.fit_transform()` needs to be an

> array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)

according to the [manual](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit_transform).

To do that you need to have the same number of features across samples. This can be achieved either by having the same number of features across images (if that makes sense in your case) or by working with images of the same size.

Comment: The reason I used "dtype=object" is because it was throwing a warning at me, should I remove it or is there a better way of dealing with the warning I'm receiving? Specifically, the warning was:


`<ipython-input-6-6c460760299f>:7: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  allFeaturesArray = np.array(allFeatures)`

Comment: I updated my post with more for clairification.